# Parameter is not valid when working with AForge.Video.FFMPEG

Tags: c#, .net

I working on application that detect motion in a video file. I was want to do that by the following:

1. read a video from hard disk.
2. convert it into frames or an array of images (e.g. array of bitmaps).
3. do some processing on the frames, including detecting motion by subtract images.
4. save the images after the processing as a video file.
5. play that video file on the form.

I google to find good way for converting a video into an array of images. But after searching i think that using FFMPEG to read and convert video.
since i use C# i try to use AForge.

Link for information about that class http://www.aforgenet.com/framework/docs/html/47582d8a-2eeb-03cf-03d5-de3e745a8a34.htm?

My problem arise when i try to use VideoFileSource Class to reead a video and display it in pictureBox. but when i try to run the program the Parameter is not valid arise in

```
Application.Run(new Form1());
```

my code::

```
public partial class Form1 : Form    
{
  System.Windows.Forms.Timer timer;
  string fileName;
  VideoFileSource videoSource;
  Thread myThread;
  public Form1()
  {
     InitializeComponent();
  }
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
     OpenFileDialog openFiel = new OpenFileDialog();
     if (openFiel.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
     {
        fileName = openFiel.FileName;
     }

     // create video source
     videoSource = new VideoFileSource(fileName);
     // set NewFrame event handler
     videoSource.NewFrame += new NewFrameEventHandler(video_NewFrame);
     // start the video source
     videoSource.Start();
  }


  // New frame event handler, which is invoked on each new available video frame
  private void video_NewFrame(object sender, NewFrameEventArgs eventArgs)
  {
     // get new frame
     Bitmap bitmap = eventArgs.Frame;
     pictureBox1.Image = bitmap;
     // process the frame
  }     
  private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {

  }
```

}

Answer (score 4):

Got the same problem. I found that using

```
(Bitmap)eventArgs.Frame.Clone()
```

solves the issue :)